# Multiple connections with node-mongodb-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native, database

I am working on a function to insert a document in a mongoDb database using the node-mongodb-native module. Everything is working, except if I call insert multiple documents back-to-back. I use a `for` loop to test how my function is reacting to multiple document insert at the same time.

```
var server = new Server("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, poolSize: 100});
var db = new Db("testDb", server, {safe: false}); 

module.exports.insert = function(document){
    var database;

    function db_open(err, db_local){
        if(err) throw err;
        database = db_local;
        database.collection("rooms", handle_insert);
    }
    function handle_insert(err, collection){
        if(err) throw err;
        collection.insert(document);
        database.close();
    }
    db.open(db_open);
};

for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
    module.exports.insert({name : "test"});
}
```

When I'm running this code I get the error `db object already connecting, open cannot be called multiple times`
To resolve the problem, I decided to create a new instance of `Server` and `Db` at each call of the function :

```
module.exports.insert = function(document){
    var database;
    var server = new Server("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, poolSize: 100});
    var db = new Db("testDb", server, {safe: false}); 

    function db_open(err, db_local){
        if(err) throw err;
        database = db_local;
        database.collection("rooms", handle_insert);
    }
    function handle_insert(err, collection){
        if(err) throw err;
        collection.insert(document);
        database.close();
    }
    db.open(db_open);
};

for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
    module.exports.insert({name : "test"});
}
```

But now I'm getting `connection closed` thrown by the db_open function
I really don't understand why my connection is closing between the moment when I'm creating `db` and when my code call `db_open`.
Have you an idea of what is happening?
Thank you :)
(Sorry if my English is not really good)

**EDIT**
I found this [website](http://christiankvalheim.com/post/32209721702/tcp-keepalive) explaining that the problem is caused by the too long tcp_keepalive time. The problem with this solution is my workstation (Cloud 9). I don't have the permission to access the file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem has anything to do with TCP keep-alive. Like the error message says, you're simply attempting to open the same connection multiple times (every time the insert method is called). Instead of calling `open()` every time, just call it once, and make sure the callback returns, before you call `insert()` for the first time. There is no hard limit to the number of simultaneous inserts you can perform on the same connection since it's all asynchronous.